# Python: writing two different dictionaries out to two different csv files

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

My program looks into a folder of text files and generates counts of two features I am looking at "SS" and "DS" and how many times they occur. So I set up a dictionary that lists the feature and how many times it occurs in the texts.

I want my SS dictionary to write out to one csv file and the DS dictionary to write out to another csv file.

Here is my code so far:

```
import glob
import re

path = "tagged texts\*.txt"

#establish counts and dictionaries
list_SS = []
list_DS = []
SScounts = {}
DScounts = {}

#generate counts of the features
for file in glob.glob(path):
    line_count = 0
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file_in:
        text = file_in.readlines()
        for line in text:
            word = line.split('_')
            if word[2] == "SS":
                list_SS.append(word[0])
            elif word[2] == "DS":
                list_DS.append(word[0])

#create dictionary for SS and write out results to file
file1_out = open("SS_counts.csv", "w+")
for w in list_SS:
    SScounts[w] = SScounts.get(w,0) + 1
for i in sorted(SScounts, key = SScounts.get, reverse=True):
    file1_out.write(str(i) + "," + str(SScounts[i]) + "\n")

#create dictionary for DS and write out results to file
file2_out = open ("DS_counts.csv", "w+")
for w in list_DS:
    DScounts[w] = DScounts.get(w,0) + 1
for i in sorted(DScounts, key = DScounts.get, reverse=True):
    file2_out.write(str(i) + "," + str(DScounts[i]) + "\n")
```

The SS dictionary comes out just fine, this what the results look like in the csv file:

```
nisha,41
rasha,19
rikusha,13
apisha,11
nishashi,8
...
```

The problem is that the second file, the DS file turns out blank, there's nothing in it. Before with some fiddling with the variable names in the dictionary I would get the results for the SS dictionary written out to both files.

I created two dictionaries after asking my prof and he said it's possible to do it from one dictionary but it'd be simpler to use two. And I guess I could just write a separate python script for the DS results but I'd like to do both in the same script.

Sooo, what's the deal? Why is the second dictionary not writing out to the second file?

Comment: PDB is your friend in cases like this.  If you are unfamiliar with it, then, I would change list_SS.append(word[0]) to pass and list_DS.append(word[0]) to print("Found DS"), assuming the files aren't massive.  If nothing shows up, then you know your issue is above that line (I would guess the files are different).  If you get something printed, then something below is the issue.  OR, print(len(list_DS)) after the first for statement to see which half of the code the error is in.

Comment: You should get into the habit of closing your files when you are done with them, e.g. `file1_out.close()`. Better yet, you should get into the habit of using the `with` statement to use files: 

with open("filename") as f:
     for line in f:
        # ... do stuff ...

Comment: Could we have some test cases to run with?

Comment: @ivan7707 I used the print statement and found that nothing was showing up in my list_DS. Then I realized exactly what happened, I ran the texts files through another script that assigned items a tag of either V-SS or V-DS, I have changed V-SS to just "SS" when I created an additional tag field. I forgot to update V-DS to DS. Therefore my DS was not populated. I changed the other program and did the update to DS, and now it works fine. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The citizens of StackOverflow cannot run your code. It often helps to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that others can run.

A crucial question: do `list_SS` and `list_DS` have data in them? Drop all of the code starting with `file1_out` and instead use this:

```
assert list_SS
assert list_DS
```

If those assertions fail, you've narrowed the problem considerably.

Another key question: can you reproduce the problem if you eliminate the globbing and file reading? Roughly like this:

```
list_SS = []
list_DS = []
SScounts = {}
DScounts = {}

text = [
    'an example line from your data files...',
    'ditto...',
    '...',
]

for line in text:
    word = line.split('_')
    if word[2] == "SS":
        list_SS.append(word[0])
    elif word[2] == "DS":
        list_DS.append(word[0])

assert list_SS
assert list_DS
```

At this point you'll have something that StackOverflow can help with ... but you might not need us by then.

Comment: assert list_DS failed, so I wondered if something was up with it, turns out that there was nothing in it, as in the text files it was marked as V-DS instead of DS, I thought I had changed it. So really it was a dumb mistake, I changed the items marked as V-DS to DS as stipulated in my code. Anyway it worked, the dictionary was populated and the script wrote out correctly to the second file. Thanks a bunch.